# How to filter dates by date and time in excel 2013?

Tags: excel

In Excel 2016, I have a column of dates like

```
2019-07-29 04:12:44 PM
```

I can change this format (or split into 2 columns), but I want to be able to do advanced date fitlers such as after, or between or before. But it should consider the date and time.

Does anyone know?

Thanks

Comment: Filter works just fine for me, based on a date/time period. What's not working for you?

Comment: but initially its plain text right, how did u get it to become a excel date format?

Comment: I tried the "text to columns" but that doesn't recognize times, it only works with dates

Comment: If you change the number format to "Number", does the cell formatting change or stay the same? Looks like a valid date format, so just verifying that you're dealing with text.

Comment: ok but how do you actually do a filter on the time portion of the date?

Comment: there doesn't seem to be any time pickers in excel you can use for filtering.

Comment: Here's a screenshot. https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxuW5.png If you want to filter on just a specific time (ignoring the date portion completely), then you'll need to create a new column with just the time portion.

Comment: If I have a date column that has both date and time, and it shows as "date filter", can I do a between operator with a date/time as both boundaries?

Comment: Actually I think that works. But I have another issue here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57263886/how-to-remove-all-formating-of-cell-values-in-excel-2013