# How to remove all formating of cell values in excel 2013?

Tags: excel

I use a 3rd party plugin (SheetJS) to dynamically create a excel file. It has columns of dates such as

```
2019-07-29 04:12:44 PM
```

If I format it as a table, the problem is excel does not recognize it as a date column, so I only get "Text Filter" as an option. But I noticed that if I copy the date value, pasted in notepad, and then copy from there, and paste back into excel, and then format as table, it recognizes it as a date column showing "Date Filter".

Is there a quick way to do this right in excel?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your SheetJS script, try to manually set your column width to 17 characters using format:

yyymmdd hh:mm:ss

This will create a 17 character value. This will also tell SheetJS that your column defined is a date column and not plain text.

```
code Snippet can be found [here][1]:


  [1]: https://jsfiddle.net/sheetjs/9xneL9wh/
```

Comment: You seem to use `YYYYMMDD HH:mm:ss`, but mine is different. Is it still 17 for me?

Comment: Or do you mean that if I want it to export as a date, the biggest column width I can use is 17 chars?

Comment: You may use: yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss and it will work. Visit the link I provided to jsfiddle, and insert your date format into the code on the site and click Run, and it will output an example spreadsheet with example date. Then you click “Format Table” and you will see you can filter by date.

Comment: You can just grab the code from that site to save you the work to re-type, edit accordingly to what works for you.

Comment: And you can change your date format and leave 17 as the date format count. {wch:17}

Comment: I tried with `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss AM/PM` and it seems to work too. I removed the code about 17, and used aoa instead of json.

Comment: Do you know if this will also work? The docs for dateNF is  here https://docs.sheetjs.com/#number-formats

Comment: I apologize for the delay, I am traveling today so I’m not in front of my computer just using my mobile phone.  Without seeing your existing code, I know for certain using the first example from earlier just modified with your date format creates the proper output that you want. Then you simply just need to do a format of the table in Excel, and you’ll be able to do a search on dates. Hope that makes sense.